# Nilpotent matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question regarding the matrix
$$
        \mathbf{A} =
        \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
             x-3&-x+3&-x+5\\
             x-2&-x+2&-x+4\\
             -1&1&-1
        \end{array}\right]
$$
I have been told that such a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is called nilpotent. Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix it should for some power $k$ give a zero matrix. I am asked to compute $\mathbf{A}^2$ and $\mathbf{A}^3$. I tried computing them in maple but none of them give a zero matrix? Why would you then call $\mathbf{A}$ a nilpotent matrix?

[image]
(If requested I could write the results in latex code :) )

Here is the exercise definition:
[image]

Is the author of the exercise wrong?

Comment: One necessary condition for any matrix to be nilpotent is that its trace is zero. Your matrix's trace isn't zero and thus cannot be nilpotent, no matter what $\;x\;$ is.

Comment: @DonAntonio The matrix trace is equal to $0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net No, it isn't. It equals $\;-1\;$ for any value of $\;x\;$ on any field. So even if the question was "for which values of $\;x\;R is the following matrix nilpotent?", the answer would be "for none".

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, you're right... $-3+2-1$ is not equal to zero. Back to basics!

Comment: @DonAntonio I now included the actual exercise definition where you can see exactly what was said. So do you then say that the the author of the exercise was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $\lambda^3+2\lambda^2+2\lambda$, so the matrix is not nilpotent. This can also be checked with the trace not being zero.

There is a typo in the exercise: if the $(3,3)$ coefficient is changed into $1$, then the statement becomes true, because the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^3$.

I fed the matrix to Pari-GP, so to get the characteristic polynomial. Changing $-1$ into $1$ in the bottom right corner makes the trace zero, so the necessary condition is fulfilled. And the characteristic polynomial confirms the typo.

By the way, the square of the (modified) matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & 2 \\
-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is independent on $x$.

The square of the original matrix is instead
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &  2 & 2x - 8 \\
-2 &  2 & 2x - 6 \\
 2 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the cube is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2x + 10 & 2x - 10 & -2x + 6 \\
-2x + 8  & 2x - 8  & -2x + 4 \\
-2       & 2       &  2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks bud. Sad when you have to use a lot of extra time trying to figure out why your answer does not add up with the exercise text, just to realize that the author did not proofread his text :/